# Bootstrap: <a> tag inside <li> doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have tried  to paste "a" tag inside "li". But I can't understand why there is no pointer cursor on  tag and href attribute doesn't work as usual.What bootstrap property locks it? It is not enough paddings for li tag? Or what I'm doing wrong? What is a better way to improve it using bootstrap classes? Any help will be appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header {
  background-color: #222222;
  height: 114px;
}
ul {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: "MyradProRegular";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 37%;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  min-height: 0px !important;
}

.search-panel-block {
  width: 40%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu-items__item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.search-panel {
  padding-top: 34px;
}
.nofloat {
  float: none;
}
.agileheader-topbar-grid {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav > li > a {
  position: static;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn {
  width: 65px;
  background-color: #f10e34;
  border-color: #f10e34;
}

.glyphicon-search {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="menu-logo">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="market-logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar default col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 pull-right">
      <ul class="menu-items nav">
        <li class="menu-items__item"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link nav-link">My account</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Wishlist</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">My Cart</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Checkout</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="agileheader-topbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 agileheader-topbar-grid agileheader-topbar-grid2 nofloat">
          <form class="search-panel">
            <div class="input-group add-on">
              <input class="form-control" name="srch-term" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is related to your `form class="search-panel"`that is overlapping the menu.

Comment: `.search-panel` is stacked above your navigation, if you try to inspect a link you end up inspecting the search form wrapper. At a glance, it look like you should be able to address this issue by nesting the *right elements* into the *right containers* and attributing the *right column classes* so that the maths sums-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to div with "agileheader-topbar" class override the menu. 
Use below code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar default col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 pull-right" style="z-index: 1;">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header {
  background-color: #222222;
  height: 114px;
}
ul {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: "MyradProRegular";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 37%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  min-height: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="menu-logo">
      <img src="logo.jpg" alt="market-logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar default col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 pull-right">
      <ul class="menu-items nav">
        <li class="menu-items__item"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link nav-link">My account</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Wishlist</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">My Cart</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Checkout</a></li>
        <li class="menu-items__item nav-link"><a href="#" class="menu-items__link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="agileheader-topbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 agileheader-topbar-grid agileheader-topbar-grid2 nofloat">
          <form class="search-panel">
            <div class="input-group add-on">
              <input class="form-control" name="srch-term" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mr Lister .navbar {  z-index: 1;}

Answer (score 0):

your nav under another div element so when you mouse enter in nav item this hasn't hovered actually, it has hovered in another div element (.agileheader-topbar). so you try this CSS

```
.agileheader-topbar { 
   width: 40; /*or is your needed */
}
```